# Adding emdash after list items in description environments throughout the document

Tags: lists, description

How can I add an emdash (`---`) after every item label in every description environment in my document?  Is there a global way to override the layout of each item?

This produces the [desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buRn5.png), but I'm manually inserting the emdash after each item:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
    \begin{description}
        \item[A] --- description        
        \item[B] --- description    
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Can it be done using just `\item[label] description` throughout my document, and only a quick override in my preamble? I found this code in **book.cls**:

```
\newenvironment{description}
               {\list{}{\labelwidth\z@ \itemindent-\leftmargin
                        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
               {\endlist}
```

So, I think I need to re-define `\makelabel`, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I only want to change the `description` environment, and not other lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the definition of `\descriptionlabel`.

```
% descriptionprob.tex  SE 572848
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
Regular descriptions:
\begin{description}
  \item[A] an item
  \item[B] another item
\end{description}

Revised description labels.
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{%
  \hspace\labelsep
  \normalfont{\bfseries #1} ---}

\begin{description}
  \item[A] an item
  \item[B] another item
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use enumitem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand\mydesclabel[1]{#1\quad{\normalfont ---}}
\setlist[description,1]{format=\mydesclabel}
\begin{document}
    \begin{description}
        \item[A]  description
        \item[B]  description
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```